# OOP how to do Class "folders"

Tags: c#, class, oop, unity-game-engine

what I want to do is:

Some script accessing:

```
//...
string Str = "aab";

void Update(){
    GUI3D.Label(Str);
    GUI3D.TextField(ref Str);
}
//...
```

in GUI3D script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public static class GUI3D {
    static void Label(string Text){
        // make text apear
    }
    static int CursorField;
    static void TextField(ref string Text){
        // changing cursor field depending on the inputs
        // change text and make it apear
    }
}
```

I hope I didn't strip down too much.
but what I want to do is that Only TextField can access the CursorField and noone else.

so that if I'd want to do:

```
    static void Label(string Text){
        // make text apear
        CursorField = 0; // that I'd get error due to protection level.
    }
```

how would I be doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You have an architecture issue. You can't hide a class member from itself. You are telling your static GUI3D class to Label() something and you are also trying to hide data from itself? Why do you need to hide the data from one member function of your GUI3D class?

Comment: like I said I'd make a child function that's GUI3D accessible BUT it's members are private, why do I need to hide it because my 3D gui is already 600 lines long and it's starting to get a bit confuzing. Also I do not care if I have to change architecture, that's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing your architecture a bit, you could try a class like this ( forgive syntax errors, I don't have a compiler handy :D ):

```
public class MyLabel {
    private string _text;
    public string Text {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; CursorField = _text.Length; }
    }

    public int CursorField { get; private set; }
}
```

As baoghal said, you can't hide a class member from itself - so wrap that functionality in an auxiliary class & only let the class itself modify CursorField.